# My multiple plot using matplotlib.pyplot subplot dont have same position

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to make 5 plots using for loop iteration in matplotlib, but my third picture moves a little bit to the right.

Do you have any idea to solve this issue?

Here is my code:

```
for i in range(len(sta310)):

    plt.figure(figsize = (15,10))
    plt.tight_layout()
    plt.subplot(5,1,i+1)
    plt.plot(t,sta310[i])
    plt.axvline(x = t[np.argmax(kurto)],color='red')
```

Comment: Not enough information for anyone to test. Please read [mcve].

Comment: I have finally figured it out. Sorry, I cant post any figure yet to make you more understanding my question since I'm just joining StackOverflow a few weeks

Answer (score 0):

I have finally figured it out. 
Sorry, I cant post any figure yet to make you more understanding my question since I'm just joining StackOverflow a few weeks

Here is the solution:

```
fig, axs = plt.subplots(5)
fig.set_figheight(10)
fig.set_figwidth(15)

for i in range(len(sta310)):
    axs[i].plot(t,sta310[i])
    axs[i].axvline(x = t[np.argmax(kurto)],color='red')
```